# Equivalent of ASP.NET WebForms ViewState in PHP?

Tags: php, viewstate

ASP.NET WebForms is outdated, but in one aspect it's far better than PHP: The **ViewState**. When you submit the form, controls stay. In PHP, you have to do everything all by yourself, rendering HTML.

Quickly, I come up with code that looks like this:

```
print('<input type="text" name="txtDate" value="' . (isset($_POST['btnSave']) ? $_POST['txtDate'] : Common::FormatDate($row['Date'])) . '" class="datepicker ' . ($dateValid ? '' : 'invalid') . '" />');
```

So I decided to at least create basic functions for rendering controls:

```
class Controls
{
    public static function TextBox($name, $id, $value, $class)
    {
        return '<input type="text" name="' . $name . '" id="' . $id . '" value="' . htmlentities($value) . '" class="' . $class . '" />';
    }
}
```

This makes things more comfortable, but it's just not the same as having a **ViewState**.

Not to mention that you have to duplicate code for both edit and create with different settings:

> **Create:** value = whatever is in `$_POST`
>   **Edit:** value = If form is submitted, take whatever is in `$_POST`, otherwise take the value from the database/model. *(ternary operator here)*

This get's even harder when you show/hide popups!

---

All in all this is a very hard and uncomfortable way and I have absolutely **no** idea where to start improving it. **What are your suggestions?**

Comment: Or use some framework or packages that do this grunt work for you. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html JavaScript is typically used to help with form handling as well. A JS framework could help as well. jQuery and AJAX are likely going to help you quickest.

Comment: It's really important that you understand that ASP.Net, with Webforms and all the other stuff that comes bundled with it is a different thing to PHP. PHP is just a core language; .Net gives you an entire framework. They're different things. If you want to compare like-for-like, you need to add a framework on top of PHP. A framework like Laravel will give you good start.